# Can't insert HOST_NAME as default

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I create table as:

```
CREATE TABLE [UserLoginAudit] (
UserLogginAuditId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EmpGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
TimeLogged DATETIME,
WorkStation VARCHAR (255)  NOT NULL DEFAULT HOST_NAME()
)
```

But when I try to do an insert like:

```
 INSERT INTO [UserLoginAudit]
               VALUES
                    (
                    @EmpGuid
                   , @Today
                    )
```

It returns:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

I check at [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and I'm using column WorksStation with default value correctly, I don't have an idea why it does not allow me to insert that value default. Any ideas?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) You should specify *which columns you're inserting into* after the table name in an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The without explicitly listing the column names, the number of values you provided doesn't align with the table definition.  You can either list only the `EmpGuid` and `TimeLogged` columns in your insert which will automatically insert the default value of the `WorkStation` column, or use these two columns and add the `WorkStation` column with the `DEFAULT` keyword to use the default value.  I would highly recommend always listing all the columns whenever you're doing an `INSERT` (or any other operation such as a `SELECT`), to avoid any problems in the future if additional columns are added.  This will also make your code much easier for others to decipher.

```
INSERT INTO [UserLoginAudit] (EmpGuid, TimeLogged)
 VALUES (@EmpGuid, @Today)
```

**With Default:**

```
 INSERT INTO [UserLoginAudit] (EmpGuid, TimeLogged, WorkStation)
 VALUES (@EmpGuid, @Today, DEFAULT)
```